# How I can extension from Any type in Swift?

Tags: swift, variables, types

I have a some function to check or helping to cast the variable to some type I want, and I make this function inside the extension like this:

```
extension Optional {
  func asJsonArrOrEmpty() -> [Any] {
    return self as? [Any] ?? [Any]()
  }
}
```

And from that I can aprroach to:

```
let any: Any? = nil
any.asJsonArrOrEmpty()
```

But for now, I want to declare a variable with non-optional and I want to using the function `asJsonArrOrEmpty()` to check the Any type variable.

Do you guys have any idea for that or I missing some syntax in this case. Thanks

Comment: That seems like a silly extension to begin with. Why not just use `Codeable`?

Comment: I know @Alexander. But that is the reason if you want custom another function for Any type. That just is a example for this question.